# Comparison of Integral sum with range

Tags: calculus

$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{98} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{k+1}{(x)(x+1)} dx$$
Prove that

A) I> $\frac {49}{50}$

B) I< ln99

I am not able to proceed as it involves calculation of comparision.

Comment: Hint: $k+1$ inside the integral doesn't depend on $x$ so you can take it outside from integral and solve it.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291997/if-i-sum98-k-1-intk1-k-frack1xx1dx-then-prove-that?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $ I = \sum^{98}_{k=1}\int^{k+1}_{k}\frac{k+1}{x(x+1)}dx.$ Then prove that $ \ln\left(\frac{49}{50}\right)&lt;I &lt;\ln(99)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291997/if-i-sum98-k-1-intk1-k-frack1xx1dx-then-prove-that)