# $I=\sum_{k=1}^{98}\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{k+1}{x(x+1)}dx$, then which of the following are correct?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{98}\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{k+1}{x(x+1)}dx$$, then which of the following are correct?

A) $I<\dfrac{49}{50}$

B) $I>\dfrac{49}{50}$

C) $I<\log_{e}99$

D) $I>\log_{e}99$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{98}(k+1)\int_{k}^{k+1}\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}dx$$
$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{98}(k+1)\left(\ln\left|\dfrac{k+1}{k+2}\right|-\ln\left|\dfrac{k}{k+1}\right|\right)$$

$$I=\left(2\ln\left|\dfrac{2}{3}\right|-2\ln\left|\dfrac{1}{2}\right|\right)+\left(3\ln\left|\dfrac{3}{4}\right|-3\ln\left|\dfrac{2}{3}\right|\right)\cdots\cdots+\left(99\ln\left|\dfrac{99}{100}\right|-99\ln\left|\dfrac{98}{99}\right|\right)$$

This is looking like a telescopic terms but middle terms are not cutting entirely.

$$I=\left(-2\ln\left|\dfrac{1}{2}\right|+99\ln\left|\dfrac{99}{100}\right|\right)-\left(\ln\left|\dfrac{2}{3}\right|+\ln\left|\dfrac{3}{4}\right|+\ln\left|\dfrac{4}{5}\right|\cdots\cdots+\ln\left|\dfrac{98}{99}\right|\right)$$

$$I=\left(2\ln2+99\ln\left|\dfrac{99}{100}\right|\right)+\ln\left|\dfrac{99}{2}\right|$$

$$I=\ln2+99\ln99-99\ln100+\ln99$$
$$I=\ln2+100\ln99-99\ln100$$
$$I=\ln\left(\dfrac{2\cdot 99^{100}}{100^{99}}\right)$$
$$I=\ln\left(198\cdot\left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{99}\right)$$

So is $198\cdot\left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{99}>99$?

Is $\left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{99}>\dfrac{1}{2}$, any way to find this if its true without finding the actual value.

Actual answers are $B,D$. Am I missing some trick here?

Comment: [Wolfram says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2899%2F100%29%5E99) $\left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{99} \approx 0.37$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri OP specifically asked to solve this "without finding the actual value".

Comment: My comment points in the direction that the inequality he is trying to prove is false, and hence that his calculations before that point must contain an error or else the answers are wrong.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, yeah according to my calculations answer should have been $C$, but answer is $D$, where am I blundering?

Comment: solution to the integral is $\ln\dfrac{x}{x+1}$, what is wrong here?

Comment: [Wolfram says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B-%281+%2B+k%29+log%28%28k+%282+%2B+k%29%29%2F%281+%2B+k%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bk%2C1%2C98%7D%5D+-+log%2899%29) answer $D$ is wrong.

Comment: so atleast we are done with the identification of correct answers, so now it comes to,  "is there any trick which am I missing here"?

Comment: Also related to : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291997/proving-that-ln-left-frac4950-right-sum98-k-1-intk1-k-frac

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\left(\dfrac{99}{100}\right)^{99} = \left(1 -\dfrac{1}{100}\right)^{99}
\leqslant \exp(-99/100).$$

Now,

$$\exp(-99/100) < \frac12 \iff \exp(-1+1/100) < \frac12 \iff 2e^{1/100} < e.$$

With $2 = e^{\log 2}$, we are left with $\log2 +\frac1{100} < 1$, and if you know the usual approximation for $\log 2 \approx 0.69$ this should suffice.

---

Even if you don't know the usual approximation, the log expansion

$$\log 2 = 1 -\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots$$

truncated at $\frac13$ yields a good enough approximation for our purposes.

Comment: $\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^4}{4}\cdots\cdots$, is valid only when $|x|<1$

Comment: This is true in the sense of radius of convergence, but the series does converge for $x=1$ to $\log 2$. It is also known as the alternating harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

Your result $$I=\log(2)+100\log(99)-99\log(100)$$ is perfectly correct.

Since they refer to $99$, let us write
$$\log(100)=\log(99+1)=\log(99)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{99}\right)\sim \log(99)+\frac 1 {99}$$ Replacing in $I$, we then have
$$I=\log(2)+\log(99)-\frac{99}{99}=\log(99)-(1-\log(2))$$ which is "just" smaller than $\log(99)$.